# CodeIgniter/PHP/GD2 Image Manipulation is playing up

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, gd2

I have a website going that takes a user's uploaded image, and makes three copies - a 'full' copy to print with (downsized to 1500x1125), a 'web' copy to display online (not coded yet), and finally a thumbnail.

So here's the code - _imageformat() is passed the parameters (which I've confirmed to be correct) from CI's Upload Class:

```
function _imageformat($fullpath, $shortpath, $width, $height)
```

{
  // We now format the image.

// First, we check if it is landscape or portrait
  if ($width >= $height) // It's landscape (or square)
  {
   // Now create the full printing image
   $fullimage = $this->_resize('l', $fullpath, $shortpath, $width, $height);
  }
  else // It's portrait
  {
   // Now create the full printing image
   $fullimage = $this->_resize('p', $fullpath, $shortpath, $width, $height);
  }

}

function _resize($type, $fullpath, $shortpath, $width, $height)
   {
    // Set up the default Image Manipulation config options
    $config['image_library']  = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image']  = $fullpath;
    $config['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;

```
// Shave the '.jpg' from the end to append some nice suffixes we'll use
$newimage = substr($fullpath, 0, -4).'_full'.".jpg";

$config['new_image'] = $newimage;

if ($type == 'l') // If it's landscape
{
 $config['width'] = 1500;
 $config['height'] = 1125;
}
else if ($type == 'p') // If it's portrait
{
 $config['width'] = 1125;
 $config['height'] = 1500;   
}

// Load the image library with the specified parameters, and resize the image!  
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
$this->image_lib->resize();

// Create a thumbnail from the full image
$config['source_image']  = $newimage;
$config['new_image']  = substr($fullpath, 0, -9)."_thumb".".jpg";
$config['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
$config['width']    = 150;
$config['height']   = 150;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

$this->image_lib->resize();

return $newimage;
```

}

**What SHOULD happen:** In my uploads folder, there are three images - the original uploaded file (we'll call it image.jpg), the resized file (named image_full.jpg), and the thumbnail (named image_thumb.jpg).

**What DOES happen:** In my uploads folder, there are only **TWO** images - the original uploaded file (image.jpg), and the resized file (image_full.jpg). No thumbnail is ever created.

**What's interesting, however, ** is that if I place the code for the Thumbnail creation *first*, it generates the thumbnail image but **NOT** the _full (resized) image.

So it appears to me that it won't ever run `$this->image_lib->resize()` twice. Why not? Is it some amateur mistake I'm making, or have I missed something obvious?! :P

Thanks!

Jack

**Edit:** I should point out that yes, I know I'm loading the `image_lib` library twice. I fathomed this was the only way of passing new parameters to it. I also tried, after resizing the full image, calling `$this->_thumbnail()` which loaded the library again there. But still the same issue occurred.

**Edit 2:** I've also tried using `$this->image_lib->clear()` - still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load the library only once and initialize it with different configs:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');

// full image stuff
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();

// thumbnail stuff
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```